# One-shot OnFocusChangeListener for an EditText on Android

Tags: java, android, memory-model

I need to implement a one-shot `OnFocusChangeListener` for my `EditText`. I.e., once the `EditText` gets focus, it do something and stop listening for the focus change event.

I assign an ananymous `OnFocusChangeListener` to my `EditText`. Then in `void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)` I call `v.setOnFocusChangeListener(null);`

It works, but I wonder why it's possible to null out the `OnFocusChangeListener` in its own method `onFocusChange`. I think I'm missing something from the Java memory model.

The code is below:

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            // do something
            v.setOnFocusChangeListener(null);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: As I understood, you think how this doesn't result in a loop. `EditText` implements `OnFocusChangeListener` interface. You first set listener and then remove that listener. Why should be there an issue?

Comment: @azizbekian, as I see from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html, `EditText` doesn't implement `OnFocusChangeListener`

Comment: My fault. There is an static inner class in `View`, called `ListenerInfo`, which retains that listener. [Source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L3566)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont panic, you cant harm the object.
There is *protected OnFocusChangeListener mOnFocusChangeListener* in the View object. Lets say it points to address 16 in your memory.

You can assign new object to it, and it will start to point lets say , at address 29. But the function that runs is from object 16.

Just the next time the OS gets that focus change, they will trigger the function at the object at memory 29, in a way this will be the last time you use this function for object at 16.

What you do is pointing at null, instead of 29, it works the same.
I hope I explained it somewhat well...

Comment: I understand. After I've called `editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {}`, the protected field `OnFocusChangeListener` holds a reference to address 16, and the method `onChange` is called on this instance. Do you have any proof from the Java docs? And sorry for nit-picking, but I'd use `code` for _protected OnFocusChangeListener mOnFocusChangeListener_ instead of italics. When I saw _protected OnFocusChangeListener mOnFocusChangeListener_, I thought I wanted to put a stress on it.

Comment: I have no proof whatsoever, Maksim. My knowledge comes from solving problems at work. So when I say this, I am 98% sure, because it works for me. But I have never read it anywhere, to be entirely sure.